# SQL Server 2005 update trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a SQL Server 2005 database and that is effected by malicious contents on daily basis. Like links or scripts. That content is mostly added in the last of database `varchar` type column.

I want an `instead of` trigger that fires when an update query runs containing following tags:    `</a>` or `<img` or `<script`.

And this trigger must cancel this update query.

Comment: Shouldn't you check this in the application logic to tell the users that they are not supposed to user these tags and have a chance to fix the content they're trying to submit?

Comment: Why not fix the SQL injection problem? [I assume you mean something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380233/can-someone-explain-this-sql-injection-attack-to-me)

Comment: Sanitize the input *before* it gets near the database. And, preferably, use a whitelist rather than a blacklist.