# Get count of NULL records in all MySQL tables based on particular field name

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL and we use a `Deleted` column to do "soft" deletes and keep history. I'm trying to write either a procedure or SQL statement which can get me the count from each table.

I believe this should be possible, as it somewhat reminds me of a SQL injection attack [I've seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380233/can-someone-explain-this-sql-injection-attack-to-me). The difference is I want to use this for good purposes :)

I reworked the code shown there, but think my syntax may be off for MySQL; how can I correct this, or should I find a better way of accomplishing this? Below is reworked from the link (so pretty sure it doesn't follow the MySQL procedure syntax).

Here is what I have so far:

```
Set ansi_warnings off

Declare @T VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR
  Select
    c.TABLE_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t
  where 
    t.table_name = c.table_name
    and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'Deleted'

OPEN Table_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
    EXEC ( 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ' + @T + 'Count FROM ' + @T + ' WHERE Deleted IS NULL' );
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T
END

CLOSE Table_Cursor

DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: is @T the table name or the number you have fetched? I would use at least 2 variables there.

Comment: @T is the table name, there is no space next to "count" so trying to get it concatenated, so when these run in bulk I can identify which table corresponds to each run.

Comment: You can not use variables for Metadata, but could use them as a type.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that helps. Instead of

```
BEGIN
    EXEC ( 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ' + @T + 'Count FROM ' + @T + ' WHERE Deleted IS NULL' );

    # would you not store that result somewhere?
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T
END
```

just try

```
BEGIN

    EXEC ( 'SELECT "@T" as tabname, COUNT(*) AS del_Count FROM ' + @T + ' WHERE Deleted IS NULL' );
    # somewhere store the number and the tabname
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T
END
```